# change multiple values with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, use-state

Hope someone could help me out.

I am trying to pass two parameters to

first parameter is setOpenModal
second parameter is setLinkVideo

I am having no issue with the first parameter, but can not get the second one to work.

The following line doesn't work too:

```
 {openModal && <Modal closeModal={setOpenModal} videoLink={setLinkVideo} />}
```

Hope someone can help me to find a soluction.

Tks in advance!!!

```
function Publicidade() {
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    const [linkVideo, setLinkVideo] = useState('');
    return (
        <div className='publicidade_root'>
            <div className='publicidade_body'>
                <div className='publi_list'>
                    <ul>
                        <li className='grid-item-1'>
                            <img id='item-1' className='img_move' data-video-link='item-1'
                                onClick={() => { setOpenModal(true) && setLinkVideo({iframe_01}) }}
                                src="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.KRDXVIDQh58FyCzeWRV2jAHaKi&pid=Api&P=0&w=122&h=173" alt=""></img></li>
                        <li className='grid-item-2'><img id='item-2' className='img_move' data-video-link='item-2' src="https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.iiNSdtlTfIksFCStwuqEKQHaKZ&pid=Api&P=0&w=300&h=300" alt=""></img></li>
                        <li className='grid-item-3'><img id='item-3' className='img_move' data-video-link='item-3' src="https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.YUVGxJdqNxT4NdWPq7hgHAHaKT&pid=Api&P=0&w=126&h=176" alt=""></img></li>
                        <li className='grid-item-4'><img id='item-4' className='img_move' data-video-link='item-4' src="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.GxK5g9AKfaRXrUDoII5jfAAAAA&pid=Api&P=0&w=109&h=164" alt=""></img></li>
                        <li className='grid-item-5'><img id='item-5' className='img_move' data-video-link='item-5' src="https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.MMxSQ1rBFPYOHJiVNQbD3QAAAA&pid=Api&P=0&w=100&h=164" alt=""></img></li>
                        <li className='grid-item-6'><img id='item-6' className='img_move' data-video-link='item-6' src="https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.X7OKyOWHoQzBzp2-_cStPgHaJQ&pid=Api&P=0&w=139&h=173" alt=""></img></li>
                        <li className='grid-item-7'><img id='item-7' className='img_move' data-video-link='item-7' src="https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.6-g9SGkt2QB8lbjvh9kXbwAAAA&pid=Api&P=0&w=122&h=163" alt=""></img></li>
                        <li className='grid-item-8'><img id='item-8' className='img_move' data-video-link='item-8' src="https://tse3.explicit.bing.net/th?id=OIP.lx5LNDQNw7TLJopHXUoFzAAAAA&pid=Api&P=0&w=125&h=165" alt=""></img></li>
                        <li className='grid-item-9'><img id='item-9' className='img_move' data-video-link='item-9' src="https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.PP2QRhakz8QpWCqfiekCrwHaLH&pid=Api&P=0&w=112&h=168" alt=""></img></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            {openModal && <Modal closeModal={setOpenModal} videoLink={setLinkVideo} />}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Publicidade;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML `img` tag, inside `onClick` property, there's code that works not as intended. In your example, two functions is between an operator, so neither of the function is being executed.
To fix your code, you should do following:

1. Create a function like `handleImageClick`, that takes in video link as argument, and calls both react `setState` functions

```
   const handleImageClick = (videoLink) => {
     setOpenModal(true)
     setLinkVideo(videoLink)
   }
```

2. Also check `Modal` component prop `videoLink`, since from example it seems that it takes value, not a function that sets video link. Or would recommend reviewing your function and variable naming. If `Modal` from inside can change `videoLink` there should be two props, for value and value setting. For example: `<Modal closeModal={setOpenModal} videoLink={videoLink} setVideoLink={setLinkVideo} />`

Answer (score 3):

You should do

```js
() => {
  setOpenModal(true);
  setLinkVideo({iframe_01})
}
```

because `setOpenModal(true) && setLinkVideo({iframe_01})` won't run the setLinkVideo function since the result of `setOpenModal(true)` is undefined

Hope that helps!

Comment: Tks a lot

would you also know how can I fix the following line:
 {openModal && <Modal closeModal={setOpenModal} videoLink={setLinkVideo} />}

I have change for the following:
 {openModal && linkVideo && <Modal closeModal={setOpenModal} videoLink={setLinkVideo} />

but it is not working

Comment: `{openModal && linkVideo && <Modal closeModal={setOpenModal} videoLink={linkVideo} />`